# Is it possible for horizontally oriented tiles to stretch their parent's width in CSS?

Tags: html, css

If I have this layout in HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
div
{
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul
{
    list-style: none;
    height: 100px;
}

li
{
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
```

I want the `<ul>` to stretch to the size of its content (400px), rather than two of the `<li>` elements wrapping down onto the next line.

Is this possible with CSS? I've always just counted the `<li>` elements with JavaScript and set the `<ul>` width like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4Y6A/); of course, it hides some because of your `overflow: hidden` on the div, [remove that and you see it is working](http://jsfiddle.net/c4Y6A/1/)):

```
ul
{
    list-style: none;
    height: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

li
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Though to actually get the `ul` to stretch in size ([it doesn't with just the above code](http://jsfiddle.net/c4Y6A/2/)), it also needs to have `display: inline-block` ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4Y6A/3/)) or a `float` applied ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4Y6A/4/)) to get it to take on the size of its contents.

Comment: Great - so it's a combination of `inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap`. Thanks!

Comment: @MartyWallace--yes, that gets the `li` elements not to wrap, then if you really want the `ul` to expand in width (otherwise, the `li`'s are just overflowing the `ul`), one of the other two things needs to be done to the `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

When you float the `<li>` like that, you effectively remove it from the `<ul>`. Are you sure that's what you want to do? Why not just float the whole list?